# Manipulating convention of cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, convention

i have a controller `PostmustController` which doesn't have any models naming  `Postmust`. it will load a model named Post how can i do it in `cakePHP`.

Comment: Reading docs is sooooo 2014... **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel** | **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$uses**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses following `array` in your `controller` it will automatically load `models` in your `controller`.

```
public $uses = array('Post');
```

Comment: This is showing this message Error: Table postmusts for model Postmust was not found in datasource default.

Comment: $uses is the array that include model into our controller.

Answer (score 3):

Learned and solved it. And there is a anotherway.

You can also use this

```
 Controller::loadModel('Post');
```

You can learn the detail from the following [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html).